# Python bugs or errors

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and I have written this simple code but there are some errors that I could not resolve :(

Please can someone help me ?

```
//initialization
str = None
var = None

def setvar(val):
""" Sets the global variable "var" to the value in 'val' """
if val:
 print "setting variable 'var' to '$val'"  // we want to print the value of 'val'
else:
 print "un-setting variable 'var'"

 var = val
 return

if __name__ == 'main':
  try:
    setvar("  hello world!  ") // use this function to set the 'var' variable
    var.strip() // we want the leading and trailing spaces removed
    print str(var)
  except:
    print "something went wrong"
```

Comment: What sort of errors are you seeing?  There are some indentation errors here that are going to make this code immediately invalid.  If these are copy-and-paste errors, you'll want to fix the and repost the code.

Comment: // is not a comment in python # is used for comments

Comment: why the use of // when you can (and in real code must) use #

Comment: Is your bug related with indentation? Indentation looks bit odd.

Comment: As well as fixing your indentation you should indent a constant `4` spaces in each indented block.

Comment: How odd, this guy had **exactly the same bugs**, maybe you can ask him how he fixed it? http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29636

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code sample.

First, assuming that you have faithfully preserved indentation when asking your question, it's all wrong. The body of `setvar` should be indented from the `def`. Please make sure you follow the PEP guidelines and use four spaces for each indentation level.

Secondly, comment markers in Python are `#` rather than `//`.

Next, if you want to affect a global variable within your function, you need to mark it so.

Fourth, `var.strip()` *returns* the new value, it doesn't operate in-place.

Also, the value of `__name__` will be `__main__` rather than `main`, in those situations where you're running this script.

And, finally, you have made `str` a null variable so you can't call it like a function.

The following works fine:

```
# initialization
var = None

def setvar(val):
    """ Sets the global variable "var" to the value in 'val' """
    global var
    if val:
        print "setting 'var' to '$val'" #  we want to print the value of 'val'
    else:
        print "un-setting 'var'"

    var = val
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        setvar("  hello world!  ") #  use this function to set the 'var' variable
        var = var.strip() #  we want the leading and trailing spaces removed
        print str(var)
    except:
        print "something went wrong"
```

One other thing which may or may not be a problem. If you want to print the *value* of `val` in that first `print` statement, you don't use `$val`. Instead, you could have something like:

```
print "setting variable 'var' to '%s'"%(val)
```

And, yes, I know you don't *need* the parentheses around a single value, that's just my coding style, and one less thing I have to remember :-)

Comment: i've done it and it works better than fine !! :D  thank you man :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use variable names inside strings in Python like you do in Perl or PHP,for example.You do like this:

```
print ("setting variable 'var' to '%s'" % val)  # we want to print the value of 'val'
```

And comments starts with '#'.

Comment: hi @Ceramic Pot, i did what you said and i still have this error: Encountered "print" at line 13, column 5. Was expecting:     "<INDENT>"

Comment: The indentation in your code is wrong.See paxdiablo's answer.